# How to create a folder in bin/Release for Visual Studio Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to create a folder in bin/Release for Visual Studio Project?

My project calls external exe file, and I would like to place that
exe file in bin/Release/External. But every time I rebuild my project
everything is removed, so I can't just manually copy the file there.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The folders inside the bin folder of your project are always deleted when you clean your solution (unless you change the project properties, but this won't solve your problem).

The simplest way of doing it is by adding the desired folder to your project and the exe file on the folder. Change the properties of the exe file to "Content" and "Copy always".

By doing that, everytime you rebuild your solution, the output will have the folder and exe file.

If the Exe file changes, you can add it as a link; ensuring you will have the latest version every time.

Comment: What if I have empty folder? I have empty folder called Temp, in it I create and remove temp files. I can't set "Copy Always" for a folder.

Comment: On the output folders, VS only copies that which will be used: Dlls that are being referenced by code and content that needs to be copied (like documents). When doing so, it will try, by default, to keep the structured of the project. This means that if a folder is empty, it will not be copied as VS detects it as a useless thing. This is how it works as far as I know. An ugly but useful in your case solution could be to create the folder you want and put a dummy file inside of it, like a "Dummy.txt" empty file.

Comment: Another approach is to create the directory from your code and then copy the file automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Or another way again..

Use [Post build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) where you write DOS commands.

For example in your case you can write:

```
mkdir  $(TargetDir)\External
xcopy  SOURCE_DIR_EXE   $(TargetDir)\External\EXE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a folder in your project, add a reference to your exe in that folder and then set the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the exe to `Copy always` / `Copy if newer`.

The folder structure of where the exe is will be replicated in the output directory.

Answer (score 2):

create a folder in the project, place the exe file in it, and set "Copy To Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer".

Answer (score 0):

Add mkdir command Post-build event command line in project options -> Build Events

Answer (score 0):

You could Use a Post-build event for that. 
Project Properties -> Build Events -> Post build event commandline "copy from a to b"

or second option, you create a folder "External" in your project and put your exe there. set the property "Copy to Output Direcotry" to "Copy always".

Answer (score 0):

Try to integrate this into the build process:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_CopyItems Include="$(your_path)\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)"
    DestinationFolder="$(BuildOutput)\External"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder with your desire name in your solution, add your files there (Add Existing Item), right click on files and set `BuildAction` to None and `CopyToOutputDIrectory` to `Copy Always` or `Copy If Newer`, rebuild your project, that is it!